# ssh-agent not working on jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline

I am newbie and trying to implement CI/CD for my hello world reactive spring project. After releasing the image to docker repo, the next step is to connect to aws ec2 and run the created image. I have already installed ssh agen plugin and tested positive in the ssh connection configured in Mangejenkins->configuration system->ssh client.

Also My system env variabes has path=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe

In the last step I am getting :

```
Could not find ssh-agent: IOException: Cannot run program "ssh-agent": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
Check if ssh-agent is installed and in PATH
[ssh-agent] FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
```

My Pipelien code:

```
pipeline {
agent any
tools {
    maven 'maven'
    jdk 'jdk1.8'
}
environment {
    registry ="my-registry"
    registryCredential=credentials('docker-credentials')
}
stages {
    stage('SCM') {
                steps {
                         git branch: 'master',
                             credentialsId:  'JenkinsGitlab',
                             url:'https://www.gitlab.com/my-repo/panda-app'
                }
     }
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            bat 'mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage'
        }
    }
    stage('Dockerize') {
        steps {
            bat "docker build -t ${registry}:${BUILD_NUMBER} ."
        }

    }
    stage('Docker Login') {
        steps{
            bat "docker login -u ${registryCredential_USR} -p ${registryCredential_PSW}"
        }
    }
    stage('Release to Docker hub') {
        steps{
            bat "docker push ${registry}:${BUILD_NUMBER}"                
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy to AWS') {
        steps {
            sshagent(['panda-ec2']) {
                    bat  "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@my-aws-host sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 ${registry}:${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                }
        }
    }

}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The build-in SSH-agent of Windows is incompatible with Jenkins SSH-Agent plugin.

I'm using the SSH-agent from the Git installation. Make sure to insert the directory(!) path of Git ssh-agent.exe before any other path, to prevent the use of Windows SSH-agent.

With a default Git for Windows installation, you can set the PATH environment variable like this:

```
path=c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;%path%
```

For me it didn't work to set the env var from within Jenkins UI. I added it through the settings app. When doing so, make sure to insert it before "%SystemRoot%\system32\OpenSSH".

Comment: The most important part of the answer is to change the PATH environment variable in the system settings of Windows and restart Jenkins if Jenkins is started as a service. Changing it in the pipeline script or with the environment injection plugin in the job configuration do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I stumbled into this problem, first of all i notice this problem will occurs in Windows or when Jenkins instance is running in Windows machine, and this how I sol

1. **You need to make sure CMD can run ssh-agent** : by default jenkins sh command will execute using CMD windows, type "ssh-agent" in CMD, if output is "unable to start ssh-agent service, error :1058" then you need to turn on that ssh-agent, use command below and execute in CMD

```
Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Manual
```

then type this to check is ssh-agent running or not

```
Get-Service ssh-agent
```

2. **You need to make sure jenkins use SSH-agent from the Git installation**

open your system environment variables in windows, make sure the order of your environment is like this

[image]

make sure all the git part is on top of "c\Windows"

restart your pc after you done that