# Issue with Jenkins Pipeline [ssh-agent] Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider

Tags: jenkins, ssh

The issue is something which is discussed widely but not in the scenario for which I am using it. In most cases it refers to cloning a git repository through SSH, that is not what I need. I need to enable/disable a scheduled task of a console application on windows system so that I can remotely deploy it.

The approaches I have tried so far are:

1. used the bundled OpenSSH that comes with windows, along with the Jenkins SSH-Agent plugin
2. removed the OpenSSH bundled with windows and used the one which comes with git, but still got the same error
3. with windows SSH, and Jenkins SSH plugin which lets you define the remote SSH host instead of just the credentials (currently what is shared in the Jenkins File)
4. same as point 3 but with git's SSH component

A little more insight, I am a noob to Jenkins/DevOps (just started a month ago) and this is my second iteration which will also creates proper releases via the GitLab API which wasn't there before hence the urgency

JenkinsFile

```
//Groovy Script for JenkinsFile

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'coreAgent' } }
    options {
        gitLabConnection( 'GitLab' )
        gitlabBuilds( builds: ['notify', 'clone', 'restore-clean', 'build', 'stop-services', 'deploy', 'start-services', 'db-update', 'archive'] )
    }
    environment {
        // Variables to change as per environment
        // Please note the only variables which my need to be modified are between the dividers below and the script steps for Sonarqube
        // the rest of the variables use these to adjust accorddingly
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        def MODULE = "****"
        def TRUNK = "Staging"
        def ENV = "****"
        def VERSION = "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        def JOB = "${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}"
        def GIT_URL = "******"
        def SOURCE = "${GIT_URL}/******/******.git"
        def AGENT_USER = "fatwa"
        def DEPLOY_USER = '\"****\"'
        def DEPLOY_PASS = '\"****"'
        def DEPLOY_SERVER = "https://*******:8172/MsDeploy.axd"
        def DB_SERVER = "*****"
        def DB_USER = "****"
        def DB_PASS = "****"
        def SONAR = "jScanner"
        def NUGET = "C:\\Users\\${AGENT_USER}\\AppData\\Roaming\\NuGet\\NuGet.config"
        def DEPLOY_PATH = "E:\\Sites\\"
        def AS = "E:\\Archives"
        def PROJECT_TOKEN = "****"
        def PROJECT_ID = "3"
        def MAIL_RECIPIENTS = "****@mail.com"
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Pipeline Variables
        def WS = "${WORKSPACE}"
        def STAMP = "${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}"
        def P_STATUS = "Null"
        // Variables to be used by the SERVER_AGENT
        def TASK_NAME = "${MODULE}consumer"
        // APP Names for MSDeploy
        def API_NAME = "${MODULE}_API"
        def WEB_NAME = "${MODULE}_WEB"
        def ADMIN_NAME = "${MODULE}_ADMIN"
        def CONSUMER_NAME = "${MODULE}CONSUMER"
        def API_APP = "\"${API_NAME}\""
        def WEB_APP = "\"${WEB_NAME}\""
        def ADMIN_APP = "\"${ADMIN_NAME}\""
        // Package Names for Deployment via MSDeploy
        def API_PKG_PATH = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_API\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\"
        def API_PACKAGE = "${API_PKG_PATH}${MODULE}_API.zip"
        def WEB_PKG_PATH = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_WEB\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\"
        def WEB_PACKAGE = "${WEB_PKG_PATH}${MODULE}_WEB.zip"
        def ADMIN_PKG_PATH = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_ADMIN\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\"
        def ADMIN_PACKAGE = "${ADMIN_PKG_PATH}${MODULE}_ADMIN.zip"
        def CONSUMER_PKG_PATH = "${WS}\\${MODULE}CONSUMER\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\"
        def CONSUMER_PACKAGE = "${WS}\\${MODULE}CONSUMER\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\${MODULE}CONSUMER.zip"
        // Artifacts for Manual Storage / Backups
        def API_ARCHIVE = "${AS}\\${MODULE}_API\\${MODULE}_API_${VERSION}_${STAMP}.zip"
        def WEB_ARCHIVE = "${AS}\\${MODULE}_WEB\\${MODULE}_WEB_${VERSION}_${STAMP}.zip"
        def ADMIN_ARCHIVE = "${AS}\\${MODULE}_ADMIN\\${MODULE}_ADMIN_${VERSION}_${STAMP}.zip"
        def CONSUMER_ARCHIVE = "${AS}\\${MODULE}CONSUMER\\${MODULE}_CONSUMER_${VERSION}_${STAMP}.zip"
        // Distrubution folders for Builds
        def API_DIST = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_API\\dist"
        def WEB_DIST = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_WEB\\dist"
        def ADMIN_DIST = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_ADMIN\\dist"
        // CS Project files for Builds
        def API_CS = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_API\\${MODULE}_API.csproj"
        def WEB_CS = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_WEB\\${MODULE}_WEB.csproj"
        def ADMIN_CS = "${WS}\\${MODULE}_ADMIN\\${MODULE}_ADMIN.csproj"
        def CONSUMER_CS = "${WS}\\${MODULE}CONSUMER\\${MODULE}CONSUMER.csproj"
        // Database Scripts to run to Maintain / Update
        def SQL_UPDATE = "${WS}\\SQL\\V1.3 LATEST\\CHANGESCRIPT\\update_script.sql"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Notification') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'notify', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "notify"
                    triggerEmail(stamp: "${STAMP}", job: "${JOB}", trunk: "${TRUNK}", version: "${VERSION}", workSpace: "${WS}", recipients: "${MAIL_RECIPIENTS}")
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'notify', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('Clone Repository') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'clone', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "clone"
                    git url: "${SOURCE}", credentialsId: 'JenkinsGitLabUser', branch: "${TRUNK}"
                    }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'clone', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('Restore & Clean') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'restore-clean', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "restore-clean"
                    bat "dotnet restore --configfile ${NUGET}"
                    bat "dotnet clean"
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'restore-clean', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "build"
                    echo 'Building API Module'
                    updateAppSettingsFile( fileId:"${ENV}_${MODULE}_API", path: "${WS}\\${MODULE}_API")
                    buildApp( type: 'Web', csFile: "${API_CS}", outDir: "${API_DIST}" )
                    echo 'Building Web Module'
                    updateAppSettingsFile( fileId:"${ENV}_${MODULE}_WEB", path: "${WS}\\${MODULE}_WEB")
                    buildApp( type: 'Web', csFile: "${WEB_CS}", outDir: "${WEB_DIST}" )
                    echo 'Building Admin Module'
                    updateAppSettingsFile( fileId:"${ENV}_${MODULE}_ADMIN", path: "${WS}\\${MODULE}_ADMIN")
                    buildApp( type: 'Web', csFile: "${ADMIN_CS}", outDir: "${ADMIN_DIST}" )
                    echo 'Building Consumer Module'
                    updateAppSettingsFile( fileId:"${ENV}_${MODULE}_CONSUMER", path: "${WS}\\${MODULE}CONSUMER")
                    buildApp( type: 'Console', csFile: "${CONSUMER_CS}", packagePath: "${CONSUMER_PKG_PATH}", packageFile: "${CONSUMER_PACKAGE}" )
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('Halt Services') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'stop-services', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "stop-services"
                    echo 'Halt API Module Services'
                    webServicesState( state: 'stop', app: "${API_APP}", deployServer: "${DEPLOY_SERVER}", name: "${API_NAME}", user: "${DEPLOY_USER}", pass: "${DEPLOY_PASS}" )
                    echo 'Halt Web Module Services'
                    webServicesState( state: 'stop', app: "${WEB_APP}", deployServer: "${DEPLOY_SERVER}", name: "${WEB_NAME}", user: "${DEPLOY_USER}", pass: "${DEPLOY_PASS}" )
                    echo 'Halt Admin Module Services'
                    webServicesState( state: 'stop', app: "${ADMIN_APP}", deployServer: "${DEPLOY_SERVER}", name: "${ADMIN_NAME}", user: "${DEPLOY_USER}", pass: "${DEPLOY_PASS}" )
                }
                echo 'Halt Consumer Application'
                sshagent( [ '****' ] ) {
                    sshcommand remote: '*****', command: "groovy -e 'taskScheduler(state: \"Disable\", task: \"${TASK_NAME}\")'"
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'stop-services', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'deploy', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "deploy"
                    echo 'Deploy API Module'
                    bat "msdeploy -source:package=${API_PACKAGE} -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -dest:auto,computerName=\"${DEPLOY_SERVER}?site=${API_NAME}\",userName=${DEPLOY_USER},password=${DEPLOY_PASS},authtype=${AUTH} -setParam:kind=ProviderPath,scope=iisApp,value=${API_NAME} -enableRule:AppOffline"
                    echo 'Deploy Web Module'
                    bat "msdeploy -source:package=${WEB_PACKAGE} -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -dest:auto,computerName=\"${DEPLOY_SERVER}?site=${WEB_NAME}\",userName=${DEPLOY_USER},password=${DEPLOY_PASS},authtype=${AUTH} -setParam:kind=ProviderPath,scope=iisApp,value=${WEB_NAME} -enableRule:AppOffline"
                    echo 'Deploy Admin Module'
                    bat "msdeploy -source:package=${ADMIN_PACKAGE} -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -dest:auto,computerName=\"${DEPLOY_SERVER}?site=${ADMIN_NAME}\",userName=${DEPLOY_USER},password=${DEPLOY_PASS},authtype=${AUTH} -setParam:kind=ProviderPath,scope=iisApp,value=${ADMIN_NAME} -enableRule:AppOffline"
                    echo 'Deploy Consumer Module'
                    bat "msdeploy -source:packge=${CONSUMER_PACAKGE} -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -dest:contentpath=${DEPLOY_PATH}${MODULE}_CONSUMER,computername=${DEPLOY_SERVER},username${DEPLOY_USER},password=${DEPLOY_PASS},authtype=${AUTH}"
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'deploy', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('Start Services') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'start-services', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "start-services"
                    echo 'Start API Module Services'
                    webServicesState( state: 'start', app: "${API_APP}", deployServer: "${DEPLOY_SERVER}", name: "${API_NAME}", user: "${DEPLOY_USER}", pass: "${DEPLOY_PASS}" )
                    echo 'Start Web Module Services'
                    webServicesState( state: 'start', app: "${WEB_APP}", deployServer: "${DEPLOY_SERVER}", name: "${WEB_NAME}", user: "${DEPLOY_USER}", pass: "${DEPLOY_PASS}" )
                    echo 'Start Admin Module Services'
                    webServicesState( state: 'start', app: "${ADMIN_APP}", deployServer: "${DEPLOY_SERVER}", name: "${ADMIN_NAME}", user: "${DEPLOY_USER}", pass: "${DEPLOY_PASS}" )
                }
                echo 'Start Consumer Application'
                sshagent( [ '****' ] ) {
                    sshcommand remote: '****', command: "groovy -e 'taskScheduler(state: \"Enable\", task: \"${TASK_NAME}\")'"
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'start-services', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('dB Update') {
            when { expression { return fileExists ("${SQL_UPDATE}") } }
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'db-update', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "db-update"
                    bat "sqlcmd -S ${DB_SERVER} -U ${DB_USER} -P ${DB_PASS} -i ${SQL_UPDATE}"
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'db-update', state: 'success'
            }
        }
        stage('Archiving') {
            steps {
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'archive', state: 'running'
                script {
                    P_STATUS = "archive"
                    backupArtifacts( package: "${API_PACKAGE}", archive: "${API_ARCHIVE}", path: "${API_PKG_PATH}" )
                    backupArtifacts( package: "${WEB_PACKAGE}", archive: "${WEB_ARCHIVE}", path: "${WEB_PKG_PATH}" )
                    backupArtifacts( package: "${ADMIN_PACKAGE}", archive: "${ADMIN_ARCHIVE}", path: "${ADMIN_PKG_PATH}" )
                    backupArtifacts( package: "${CONSUMER_PACKAGE}", archive: "${CONSUMER_ARCHIVE}", path: "${CONSUMER_PKG_PATH}" )
                }
                updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'archive', state: 'success'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            script {
                createRelease( token: "${PROJECT_TOKEN}", url: "${GIT_URL}", pID: "${PROJECT_ID}", jobNum: "${VERSION}")
            }
        }
        always {
            script {
                emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''',
                mimeType: 'text/html',
                subject: "[Jenkins] ${JOB}",
                to: "${MAIL_RECIPIENTS}",
                replyTo: "${MAIL_RECIPIENTS}",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
            }
        }
        failure {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: "${P_STATUS}", state: 'failed'
        }
        aborted {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: "${P_STATUS}", state: 'canceled'
        }
        cleanup {
            script {
                cleanUpFolders ( type: "Web", dist: "${API_DIST}", space: "${WS}", mod: "${MODULE}", comp: "API" )
                cleanUpFolders ( type: "Web", dist: "${WEB_DIST}", space: "${WS}", mod: "${MODULE}", comp: "WEB" )
                cleanUpFolders ( type: "Web", dist: "${ADMIN_DIST}", space: "${WS}", mod: "${MODULE}", comp: "ADMIN" )
                cleanUpFolders ( type: "Console", space: "${WS}", mod: "${MODULE}", comp: "CONSUMER" )
            }
        }
    }
}
// Methods to be used in the pipeline
def triggerEmail(Map config = [:]) {
    def dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmm")
    def formattedDate = dateFormat.parse(config.stamp)
    def emailContent = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <style>
                .styled-table {
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                  margin: 25px 0;
                  font-size: 0.9em;
                  font-family: sans-serif;
                  min-width: 400px;
                  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                }
                .styled-table thead tr {
                  background-color: #009879;
                  color: #ffffff;
                  text-align: left;
                }
                .styled-table th,
                .styled-table td {
                  padding: 12px 15px;
                  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
                  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
                }
                .styled-table th:first-child,
                .styled-table td:first-child {
                  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
                }
                .styled-table th:last-child,
                .styled-table td:last-child {
                  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                }
                .styled-table tbody tr {
                  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
                }
                .styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
                  background-color: #f3f3f3;
                }
                .styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
                  border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
                }
                .styled-table tbody tr.active-row {
                  font-weight: bold;
                  color: #009879;
                }
                .styled-table td:first-child,
                .styled-table th:first-child {
                  border-left: none;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <br>
          <h3> Build triggered at ${formattedDate}</h3>
          <table class="styled-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Project</th>
                <td>${config.job}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Branch</th>
                <td>${config.trunk}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Version</th>
                <td>${config.version}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Workspace</th>
                <td>${config.workSpace}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </body>
        </html>
    """
    def recipients = config.recipients ?: ''
    if (config.job && config.trunk && config.version && config.workSpace && recipients) {
        emailext body: emailContent,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        subject: "[Jenkins] ${config.job}",
        to: recipients,
        replyTo: recipients,
        recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']]
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid input provided, all fields are required'
    }
}
def buildApp(Map config = [:]) {
    if (!['Console', 'Web'].contains(config.type)) {
        error "Invalid parameter passed, acceptable values are Console or Web"
        return
    }
    if (config.type == 'Console') {
        if (!config.csFile) {
            error "Missing csFile parameter"
            return
        }
        if (!config.packagePath) {
            error "Missing packagePath parameter"
            return
        }
        if (!config.packageFile) {
            error "Missing packageFile parameter"
            return
        }
        bat "msbuild ${config.csFile} /t:Publish /p:configuration=release"
        bat "msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dirPath=\"${config.packagePath}\" -dest:package=\"${config.packageFile}\""
    }
    if (config.type == 'Web') {
        if (!config.csFile) {
            error "Missing csFile parameter"
            return
        }
        if (!config.outDir) {
            error "Missing outDir parameter"
            return
        }
        bat "msbuild ${config.csFile} /p:OutDir=${config.outDir} /p:Configuration=Release /p:GenerateSerializationAssemblies=false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination=false /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false"
    }
}
def taskScheduler(Map config = [:]) {
    if (!['Enable', 'Disable'].contains(config.state)) {
        error "Invalid state parameter passed, acceptable values are Enable or Disable"
        return
    }
    if (!config.task) {
        error "Missing task parameter"
        return
    }
    if (config.state == 'Disable') {
        bat "schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"\\${config.task}\" /End"
        bat "schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"\\${config.task}\" /Disable"
    } else {
        bat "schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"\\${config.task}\" /Enable"
        bat "schtasks.exe /Change /TN \"\\${config.task}\" /Run"
    }
}
def webServicesState(Map config = [:]) {
    try {
        if (!config.containsKey('state')) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing 'state' parameter")
        }
        if (!config.containsKey('app') || !config.containsKey('deployServer') || !config.containsKey('name') || !config.containsKey('user') || !config.containsKey('pass')) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing required parameters: 'app', 'deployServer', 'name', 'user', 'pass'")
        }
        if (!['start', 'stop'].contains(config.state)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid state '${config.state}', acceptable values are 'stop' and 'start'")
        }
        def recycleMode = config.state == 'start' ? 'StartAppPool' : 'StopAppPool'
        def computerName = "${config.deployServer}?site=${config.name}"
        def msdeployCommand = "msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp=${config.app},recycleMode=\"${recycleMode}\",ComputerName=\"${computerName}\",UserName=${config.user},Password=${config.pass},AuthType=\"Basic\""
        echo "Executing msdeploy command: ${msdeployCommand}"
        bat msdeployCommand
    } catch (e) {
        echo "Error executing webServicesState: ${e.message}"
        throw e
    }
}
def backupArtifacts(Map config = [:]) {
    // Check if package file path is provided
    if (!config.package) {
        error "Package file path is missing"
        return
    }
    // Check if archive directory path is provided
    if (!config.archive) {
        error "Archive directory path is missing"
        return
    }
    // Check if package file exists
    if (!new File(config.package).exists()) {
        error "Package file does not exist"
        return
    }
    // Check if archive directory exists
    if (!new File(config.archive).exists()) {
        error "Archive directory does not exist"
        return
    }
    // Execute the commands if input validation passes
    bat "xcopy ${config.package} ${config.archive}* /f /g /k /x /v /y"
    archiveArtifacts artifacts: '${config.path}/**/*.zip,', allowEmptyArchive: true
}
def createRelease(Map config = [:]) {
    // Validate inputs
    if (!config.token || !config.url || !config.pID || !config.jobNum) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing required configuration keys")
    }
    try {
        // Get the latest release version from tag_name of GitLab releases
        def latestVersion = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "curl -s --header \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${config.token}\" \"${config.url}/api/v4/projects/${config.pID}/releases\" | jq -r \".[0].tag_name\"")
        // Modify tag_name to append the job number after the decimal
        def newVersion = latestVersion.substring(0, latestVersion.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".${config.jobNum}"
        // Get latest commit messages since last build
        def commitMessages = bat(returnStdout: true, script: "git log --no-merges --pretty=format:\"commit %h%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate:   %cd%n%n    %s%n\" HEAD~1..HEAD")
        // Create new release in GitLab
        withEnv(["NEW_VERSION=${newVersion}"]) {
            bat "curl --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" --header \"PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${config.token}\" --data \"{ \\\"tag_name\\\": \\\"${NEW_VERSION}\\\", \\\"description\\\": \\\"${commitMessages}\\\"}\" --request POST \"${config.url}/api/v4/projects/${config.pID}/releases\""
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create release: ${e.getMessage()}")
    }
}
def updateAppSettingsFile(Map config = [:]) {
    if (!config.fileId || config.fileId.isEmpty()) {
        error "Invalid file ID provided."
    }
    if (!config.path || config.path.isEmpty()) {
        error "Invalid path provided."
    }
    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: "${config.fileId}", variable: "SETTINGS")]) {
        if (!fileExists("${SETTINGS}")) {
            error "The settings file does not exist."
        }
        bat "copy \"${SETTINGS}\" \"${config.path}\\appsettings.json\" /D /V /Y"
    }
}
def cleanUpFolders(Map config = [:]) {
    if (!config.type || (config.type != "Web" && config.type != "Console")) {
        error "Invalid type provided. Acceptable values are Web or Console."
    }
    if (config.type == "Web") {
        bat "del /f /q /s \"${config.dist}\\*.*\""
        bat "del /f /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}_${config.comp}\\bin\\*.*\""
        bat "del /f /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}_${config.comp}\\obj\\*.*\""
        bat "rmdir /q /s \"${config.dist}\""
        bat "rmdir /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}_${config.comp}\\bin\""
        bat "rmdir /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}_${config.comp}\\obj\""
    }
    else if (config.type == "Console") {
        bat "del /f /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}${config.comp}\\bin\\*.*\""
        bat "del /f /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}${config.comp}\\obj\\*.*\""
        bat "rmdir /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}${config.comp}\\bin\""
        bat "rmdir /q /s \"${config.space}\\${config.mod}${config.comp}\\obj\""
    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience, windows SSH agent isn't compatible, but Git's working fine. Make sure folder path of Git's SSH agent is added at the *beginning* of system PATH environment variable. Change it in the system environment variables dialog and restart the Jenkins service. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61724900/7571258

Comment: I never restarted the jenkins node/agent service, let me try that

Comment: tried it and still didn't work, just going to resort to having another agent running on the remote server to which i was attempting to connect to via ssh